# Find a separable extension of $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}(X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I got this exercise: Let $p>2$ be a prime number, and let $F$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$. Find the largest field $E$ in between $F(X)$ and $F(X^{1/2p})$ such that $E$ is a separable extension over $F(X)$.

It seems that I need to find all elements in $F(X^{1/2p})$ that are separable over $F(X)$. I know that a finite field of characteristic $p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbf{F}_{p^n}$, but I am not sure how this would help solving the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I'd look at the intermediate field $F(X^{\frac12})$ and see what I could say about its separability, and then look at $F(X^{\frac1{2p}})$ over it and see what etc

Comment: You need to recognize that $E(a^{1/p})/E(a)$ is purely inseparable.

Comment: @ancientmathematician has said it all. Since $F(X^{1/2})$ is separable over $F(X)$ of degree two, there is no intermediate field between this and the (inseparable) big field. So you have in hand the maximal separable over $F(X)$. (Don’t forget that the compositum of two separable extensions is separable.)